# How can you display ticks on a QML RangeSlider object?

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to create a RangeSlider in QML that also has ticks at the specified step size. This [is possible](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-sliderstyle.html) with the Slider component, but I have not managed to adapt this to a RangeSlider. Of course, I could achieve a very hacky solution by positioning an image with ticks just below the slider, but this is an unflexible and non-adaptive workaround that I'd like to avoid. Do I have to write my own QML component just for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to implement ticks yourself currently. Here's a quick example:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    RangeSlider {
        id: rangeSlider
        first.value: 0.25
        second.value: 0.75

        readonly property int tickWidth: 1

        Item {
            id: rowLayout
            parent: rangeSlider.background
            width: parent.width
            height: 8
            anchors.top: parent.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 12

            property int spacing: 5

            Repeater {
                model: rangeSlider.background.width / (parent.spacing + rangeSlider.tickWidth) + 1
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    x: index * (rowLayout.spacing + rangeSlider.tickWidth)
                    y: parent.height - height
                    implicitWidth: major ? rangeSlider.tickWidth + 1 : rangeSlider.tickWidth
                    implicitHeight: major ? 8 : 6
                    color: "#444"

                    readonly property bool major: index % 5 == 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When run with the Material style, it looks like this:

[image: range slider]

Comment: looks like ticks area is not considered as part of total height of control. When putting this into Column, looks like this:  https://i.imgur.com/e16tRd1.png   Can you suggest how to fix it?

Comment: By experimenting found that `bottomPadding: rowLayout.height + rowLayout.anchors.topMargin` does the trick.